# Where in the signal chain is Channel Equalization applied?

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, signal-detection, equalization, multipath

I am reading about channel equalization and I am somewhat confused on where in the signal chain channel equalization is normally applied and if it's before or after a correlator detector or matched filter.

My confusion is that if equalization occurs before matched filtering/correlator detection, then a training sequence used to estimate the channel will need to be based upon the output of the ADC, not of the matched filter. So if a pseudo-random sequence is used as a pilot tone it won't consist of symbols but of some other modulation type.

If the equalization is based upon the symbol rate output of the matched filter how are fractional delays handled?

Comment: This really does depend on what you're doing. Often, you can model an equalizer as an LTI system (e.g. a filter); and then, you can use the **commutation property** of convolution to prove it doesn't matter where you do what. The interesting question is where you get your channel state information from; but that's not necessarily the place where you *apply* your equalization!

Comment: I see, but in terms of estimating the channel(for example using a training sequence) does the pilot sequence consist of a sequence of symbols or something else? I have a read a few papers on this but no one actually talks about where in the signal chain this is applied.

Comment: It consists of something of known properties. Often it's easiest to use symbols, because, hey, you already have a transmitter for these, but sometimes the symbols might have disadvantegous properties (e.g. not DC-free enough, no possibility to make white in spectrum), so that you use something else.

Comment: As in everything you do in engineering, *it depends*; you take a problem and you solve it. The solution to the problem (here: estimating a channel) depends on your problem's specifics.

Comment: Ok so if you're using symbols you apply your LS criteria using the output of the correlator? Again it's not clear at all where this is actually applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, any matched filtering would be done before equalization, since there is no practical advantage that I am aware of to applying a matched filter afterwards.  Most textbooks that I've read present an architecture in which a matched filter is applied first, the signal is sampled at 1 sample/symbol, then an equalizer is applied at 1 sample/symbol.  But it does not have to be this way: you could apply a matched filter, but not downsample, then apply a fractionally-spaced equalizer and sample the output at 1 sample/symbol; or your could skip the matched filter entirely and apply an equalizer directly, in which case the equalizer would adapt to include both the matched filter and equalizer response.

Regarding fractional delays: if the equalizer is symbol-spaced, then we must perform symbol timing recovery prior to downsampling so that we sample the matched filter output at the correct times.  We need to perform symbol timing recovery anyway to correct any rate offsets, but if we are downsampling to 1 sample/symbol, we must also get the symbol clock phase correct.  If the equalizer is fractionally-spaced, then it can adaptively refine the sample time, although it can't correct any substantial rate offsets.  This is an advantage of using a fractionally-spaced equalizer; the primary disadvantage is the higher input sampling rate.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In the case the delay time spacing is less than the symbol time, does this cause a problem for symbol spaced equalizers? I'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking.  But if you use a symbol-spaced equalizer, the sample rate must be exactly equal to the symbol rate and the sample times (which you could look at as the delay) must also be accurate.  If not, this will degrade the performance of the symbol-spaced equalizer and the link as a whole.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say if the delayed copy was delayed a fraction of the symbol time if this would cause an issue. Also it seems like least squares channel estimation is normally based upon a pilot sequence of symbols and thus would need to be after a correlator/matched filter(otherwise you're just sampling individual points).

Comment: A fractional delay that wasn't compensated for would indeed cause an issue.  This is one advantage of fractionally-spaced equalization.  As for channel estimation, yes, it is normally based on a pilot sequence.  While you would probably put it after a matched filter, I don't see why you have to.  The matched filter is just a known linear, time-invariant system in your channel.

Comment: The equalizer could be put before the matched filter but the matched filter output would need to be sampled at the symbol rate for channel estimation right? If you don't apply the matched filter before sampling for channel estimation you're just sampling the signal at the symbol rate and losing a ton of information(also your pilot sequence wouldn't consist of pilot symbols anymore).

Comment: In principle you could put the equalizer before the matched filter, but I don't know why you would.  I don't follow the thinking about "sampling the signal at the symbol rate and losing a ton of information."  Both a symbol-rate channel estimate (pilot symbols in, 1 sample/symbol coming out) and a multi-rate channel estimate (pilot symbols in, multiple samples/symbol coming out; essentially, the effective pulse shape of the channel) are valid channel estimates and useful in different contexts.

Comment: If you don't run your input signal through a matched filter/correlator and only sample the incoming signal at the symbol rate - you're essentially down sampling right? No correlation takes place and the output isn't a symbol. I understand the idea of having the adaptive filter acting to combine the matched filter and equalizer but then the adaptive filter will need to be implemented at the ADC rate not the symbol rate.

Comment: @FourierFlux that'd be *undersampling* in my vocabulary, but different people use different terminology when it comes to downsampling. Anyway, why on earth would you do that? Your equalizer would run on the full sampling rate, not a random polyphase component (you **could** do that if you have a lot of restrictions on how the channel behaves. Again, *it depends*: these are systems. None of the components has a right position unless you define the overall purpose.)

Comment: You wouldn't downsample to 1 sample/symbol prior to applying a matched filter or a combined matched filter/equalizer.  In either case, you'd have a multi-rate filter whose input is multiple samples/symbol and output is at 1 sample/symbol.  I heartily agree with @MarcusMüller's assertion that nothing has a "right position," but that it depends on the system.  In many cases, there are multiple ways to do it.

Comment: Interesting, if you used a multi-rate filter the updates would be applied each symbol right?

Comment: You'd compute the filter output once per symbol, yes.

Comment: If you were using a LS channel estimate, your number of pilot symbols would need to be at least equal to your number of channel taps right? Or would your LS estimate be based upon sampling at the same rate as the filter so you would end up using mid-sample outputs of the filter for the LS estimate?

Comment: Oops, I meant to say mid-symbol.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the channel estimate can be single rate (1 sample/symbol in, 1 sample/symbol out) or multi-rate (1 sample/symbol in, multiple samples/symbol out).  The issue is its length in time, and yes, in general it would need to be at least as long as the channel impulse response.